# How to get content from database in helper

Tags: codeigniter

Hi: In code igniter for select box I want to display the content from database. I unable to receive content from database. How do I display with helper. If i using the helper I get the following error. How do get the same.

```
Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in G:\xampp\htdocs\lokalpickup_ci\admin\application\helpers\lib_helper.php on line 79
```

Comment: add your code in which your are getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is using $this. Actually in helper cannot use $this in CodeIgniter. You need to get the instance to some variable then can use it like $this.

```
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('Dynamic_dropdown', 'dd_model');
```

The below code I got for a dynamic select control generated from PHP Code Generator. You can use something like this.

```
    function form_dynamic_dropdown($tablename, $fieldDetails, $valueColumn, $displayColumn, $default='') {
        if (!is_array($fieldDetails)) {
            log_message('error', 'Field details should be an array for dynamic dropdown', TRUE);
            return;
        }
        $field_properties = '<select';
        foreach ($fieldDetails as $key => $value) {
            $field_properties .= ' ' . $key . ' = \'' . $value . '\'';
        }
        $field_properties .= '>';

        $CI = & get_instance();
        $CI->load->model('Dynamic_dropdown', 'dd_model');
        $field_properties .= '<option value=\'\'>';
        $field_properties .= 'Select';
        $field_properties .= '</option>';

        if(isset($fieldDetails['name']) && isset($_POST[$fieldDetails['name']]))
            $default = $_POST[$fieldDetails['name']];

        $condition = array();
        $results = $CI->dd_model->search($condition, $tablename);
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($result->$valueColumn == $default)
                $field_properties .= '<option value=\'' . $result->$valueColumn . '\' selected>';
            else
                $field_properties .= '<option value=\'' . $result->$valueColumn . '\'>';
            $field_properties .= $result->$displayColumn;
            $field_properties .= '</option>';
        }
        $field_properties .= '</select>';
        return $field_properties;
    }
```